# Select 0 when no row found by criterium

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I can't figure out how to include rows which was not found by query. Query looks like:

```
select 'EXPORT',count(z.zamodbpoz_id),k.nazwa,sum(z.ilosc) from klaswytw k
inner join wytwor w on w.klaswytw_id = k.klaswytw_id
inner join zamodbpoz z on w.wytwor_id = z.wytwor_id
inner join zamodb za on za.zamodb_id = z.zamodb_id
where 
k.klaswytw_id in (
84,88,89,92,93,119,133,134,199,235,237,286,287
,289,290,291,434,440,108,288,481,138,137,206,207
,212,91,136,135,220,218,85,407,411,115,410,87,500
,86,435,219,106,405,436,116,243,441,442,443,29,425
,32,426,23,31,96,124,422,22,38,39,40,428,486,132,430
,36,432,496,482,487,141,140,226,131,69,190,478,477,18,431)
 and 
 za.typzamodb_id in (13,12,19,21) and month(za.datdok) = 5 and year(za.datdok) = 2017
GROUP by k.nazwa
order by k.nazwa
```

`EXPORT  | 12   |  LT11A1_XYZ    | 33.000
 EXPORT  |  2   |  LT1300_ABC    | 45.000`

It returns 43 rows (example above), so it means that 43 `k.klaswytw_id` was found from range. How to change this query to include not founded `k.klaswytw_id` ? Of course it will return `NULL` or `0` values, but I can make it.

Comment: Do you have a table (somewhere) that includes all of those IDs? if so, what is it called? Or, is it case that `wytwor` does contain all those IDs? If so, use a `LEFT JOIN`, not a `INNER JOIN`. Also, move any references to those tables to the `ON` clause that are in the `WHERE` (otherwise it'll turn into an implicit `INNER JOIN`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```
select 'EXPORT',count(z.zamodbpoz_id),k.nazwa,sum(z.ilosc)
from
  (
    select *
    from klaswytw
    where klaswytw_id in (
                84,88,89,92,93,119,133,134,199,235,237,286,287
                ,289,290,291,434,440,108,288,481,138,137,206,207
                ,212,91,136,135,220,218,85,407,411,115,410,87,500
                ,86,435,219,106,405,436,116,243,441,442,443,29,425
                ,32,426,23,31,96,124,422,22,38,39,40,428,486,132,430
                ,36,432,496,482,487,141,140,226,131,69,190,478,477,18,431)
  ) k
left join wytwor w on w.klaswytw_id = k.klaswytw_id
left join zamodbpoz z on w.wytwor_id = z.wytwor_id
left join zamodb za on za.zamodb_id = z.zamodb_id and za.typzamodb_id in (13,12,19,21) and month(za.datdok) = 5 and year(za.datdok) = 2017
GROUP by k.nazwa
order by k.nazwa
```

Comment: Works perfect. Thank you so much !

Answer (score 0):

You may want to change the where statement to have an OR after the k.klasytw_id in () statement so that it will return results that have the correct k.klaswytw_id OR results that have the correct date/typzamodb_id.

```
 where 
 k.klaswytw_id in (
 84,88,89,92,93,119,133,134,199,235,237,286,287
 ,289,290,291,434,440,108,288,481,138,137,206,207
 ,212,91,136,135,220,218,85,407,411,115,410,87,500
 ,86,435,219,106,405,436,116,243,441,442,443,29,425
 ,32,426,23,31,96,124,422,22,38,39,40,428,486,132,430
 ,36,432,496,482,487,141,140,226,131,69,190,478,477,18,431)
  OR
  za.typzamodb_id in (13,12,19,21) and month(za.datdok) = 5 and 
 year(za.datdok) = 2017
```

Or if you are looking to include results where the k.klaswytw_id doesn't match the w.klaswytw_id you will want to look into Left/Right/Outer joins.

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: The problem is, that none of mentioned JOINS dont help me solving this problem. klaswytw.klaswytw_id does not match with wytwor.klaswytw_id

Comment: Using a FULL OUTER JOIN instead of an INNER JOIN should return all results from both klaswytw and wytwor even if their respective klaswytw_id's don't match. I am not well versed enough to know how your other JOIN statements will affect that though...

Comment: Can you provide a sample data and desired output?